# How to set reminder for recurring tasks created through Apex?

Tags: apex

I am creating recurring tasks through Apex for one month starting today for every day. I am also setting the field `IsReminderSet` to `TRUE` but in the UI, reminder is unchecked.

Here is the code that can be run in Anon window:

```
Task obj = new Task();
obj.WhoId = [SELECT Id FROM Lead LIMIT 1];
obj.IsRecurrence = true;
obj.RecurrenceStartDateOnly = System.today();
obj.RecurrenceInterval = 1;
obj.RecurrenceEndDateOnly =  System.today().addMonths(1);
obj.RecurrenceType = 'RecursDaily';
obj.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();
obj.IsReminderSet = true; //setting the reminder to true.
obj.Subject = 'Test';
insert obj;
```

Task created in UI(Reminder checkbox is not checked):
[image]

From the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_task.htm), I see that there is another field named `ReminderDateTime` but this field needs absolute value. How can I set this in this situation?

**NOTE**:

1. I have enabled Activity reminders at the org level and user level.
2. I found the same question [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000093XSIAY) but no answer.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the documentation on the **[`Event`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_event.htm)** object, I believe you are looking for the **`IsReminderSet`** and **`ReminderDateTime`** fields. Note they can only be set when `IsChild` is true. If you want to set it equal or relative to the recurrence date, you should be able to just reference `StartDateTime` and use methods such as `Datetime.addHours(...)`, etc. or `Datetime.date()` to get that value.

For `Task`, you should just be able to reference `ActivityDate` instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74945/discussion-between-javanoob-and-adrian-larson).